# GitHub push to AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, git

I am using GitHub for code management.
I am using Amazon AWS Elastic Beanstalk as a server.

Amazon announced that you can use Git to push code to the application server. However, to do this I'd have to let go of GitHub as they are essentially replacing the git server.

Is there any way to have the best of both worlds?

I don't necessarily need to "deploy" everytime I push, but I'd like to have it uploaded as a "Version", and then I can deploy the version I want anytime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Git is distributed. You can use Github and Elastic Beanstalk (and any number of other hosts, like Bitbucket, or your own personal hosted Git server) in the same repository.

When you want to push to Github, you'd do a `git push`. When you want to push it all to EB, you'd do `git aws.push`.

Comment: You mean within the same folder in my localbox, where I have cloned my GitHub repository, I can also push to AWS?

Comment: Yes. Just do the AWS setup steps from the docs in that repo.